# Does inserting multiple documents in a Meteor Collection work the same as pure mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

It seems I can't do a multiple insert in Meteor the same way it is [described here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) in the Mongodb documentation...

In my js console :

`> Test.insert([{name:'hello'},{name:'hello again'}])`

It returns

```
  "g3pq8GvWoJiWMcPkC"
```

And when I go

`Test.find().fetch()`

I get the following :

```
Object
0: Object
name: "hello"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
name: "hello again"
__proto__: Object
_id: "g3pq8GvWoJiWMcPkC"
__proto__: Object
```

It seems Meteor creates a super document encompassing the two I'm trying to insert as separate ones.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the Meteor leaderboard [example code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/leaderboard/leaderboard.js), it looks like you cannot bulk insert. You can either use a loop or underscore iteration function.

Using underscore,

```
var names = [{name:'hello'},{name:'hello again'}]

_.each(names, function(doc) { 
  Test.insert(doc);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Prashant, that's what I did. Weird that bulk insert doesn't work.

Comment: May I suggest you edit it the each to `_.each(names, function(doc) {
  Test.insert(doc);
})` because otherwise the document would be nested in `name`

Comment: I recommend using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead, as it is an alternative to _.each() that is now supported in Node and many web browsers.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, underscore falls back to native implementations when available, so would just be a matter of preference using native one directly or letting underscore handling it for you.

Comment: **this has not changed in 2015**: https://forums.meteor.com/t/bulk-insert-without-using-loops-collection-insert/2848/3

Comment: Not the answer for the question being asked. This is not bulk insert, it is doing many single inserts. It is not atomic, and should the database connection break or some other error occurs during the _.each loop, you will only have partial persistence and need to roll back.

Answer (score 7):

You should always use [bulk insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk.insert/) for these things.
Meteor doesn't support this out of the box.
You could use the [batch insert plugin](https://atmospherejs.com/mikowals/batch-insert) or access the node Mongodb driver to do it natively:

```
var items = [{name:'hello'},{name:'hello again'}],

    testCollection = new Mongo.Collection("Test"),
    bulk = testCollection.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    bulk.insert(  items[i] );
}

bulk.execute();
```

Note that this only works on mongoDB 2.6+

Comment: One gotcha I just noticed to this is you must add your own `_id` (using `Random.id()`). As the bulk insert doesn't add the `_id` in the way it's supposed to. It adds it as a weird object.

Answer (score 4):

As of Nov 2018, you can just use [rawCollection](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection) to access the collection returned by Mongo Driver and then insert an array of documents as per the [Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#insert-multiple-documents).

Example:

```
let History = new Mongo.Collection('History');

History.rawCollection().insert([entry1, entry2, entry3]);
```

Comment: The client side implementation of mongodb, minimongo, doesn't implement all the same functionalities and I don't think it can insert arrays of documents no. Bulk insert makes a lot of sense to minimize access to the database but client side it probably doesn't matter much if you just do a loop and insert one by one?

Comment: Using `rawCollection` will not trigger pub/sub reactivity or `simple-schema` hooks or automatically add `_ids`. But it does do the trick if you don't need all the Meteor goodness.

Answer (score 1):

For inserting multiple records in your collection you can use [mikowals:batch-insert](https://github.com/mikowals/batch-insert) plugin.

a simple example it would be :

```
var names = [{name:'hello'},{name:'hello again'}];
yourCollection.batchInsert(names);
```

What you get here is using only one connection you will be able to insert all data in one go same as mongo bulk insert operation.