# mongoDB doesn't insert in the document's root

Tags: javascript, mongodb, insert, meteor

I have a collection in var like this :

```
var temp = Collection.find({nom: "lol"}).fetch();
```

I change the _id here

```
Collection2.insert(temp);
```

In mongoDB I have this :

```
{
    "0" : {
       _id: "65462984521651" //<- The id I have change
       //Some other data
       //....
      },
    _id : "dvhssdhvflidsfjhv"
}
```

How can I insert the document in the root and not in "0" ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cursor.fetch` method](http://docs.meteor.com/#fetch) always returns an array.
The [`collection.insert` method](http://docs.meteor.com/#insert) always expects a single document, which is *unlike* the native MongoDB JS driver where it will accept bulk-inserts.

How to insert multiple documents has been covered in [Does inserting multiple documents in a Meteor Collection work the same as pure mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306390/does-inserting-multiple-documents-in-a-meteor-collection-works-the-same-as-pure).

Consider the following (instead of `Collection2.insert(temp)`):

```
temp.forEach(function(doc) {
    Collection2.insert(doc);
});
```

---

Also consider naming your variable something different than `temp` ...temp what? temp total posts? temp messages? temp usernames? Same goes for `Collection` and `Collection2`. Then again, these names could simply be for this specific SO question; so if that's the case, ignore this note!